# Wait of code execution till event is not done in c#

Tags: c#

I have c# code which send data frames over the CANBus continuously and CAN read back response from the slave.

I wants to send some 160bytes of data frames to slave continue from c# code. My c# code has the timer of 10ms which read the status from slave whether slave has sent the response back or not. meanwhile the main code continue send 8 bytes of frames to the slave.

Now I want to wait and watch does slave has sent the data back to the master or not, once i got the response i will send the next frame to the salve.

Now in c# how would i do check or wait of code execution does the flag is set or not in the timer .. I tried Thread.Sleep(100); but side effects of this is that timer interrupt function is not executing. similarly I have tried do{}while loop also but same situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
RakPat

Comment: are you reading via serial port?

Comment: as some people seem to want it, please paste some relevant code to show what you are doing

Comment: I am repeatedly transmitting data using the following API.
if (CANdoImport.CANdoTransmit(CANdoUSB, IDE, BOARD1ADD, RTR, (byte)numericUpDown1.Value, Data, 0, 0) == CANdoImport.CANDO_SUCCESS)